# How to retrieve all selected options through pages of pagination after submitting form php

Tags: php, select, pagination

I have a number of select option which I paginated to display 5 select option per page and this works fine like this

```
    <form method="post" action="sel.php">
    <?php
    ---------------------------------
//Pagination script here
----------------------------------------
//Here, I retrieve some values from database 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE startunix > '$nowtime' ORDER BY starttime LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage" ;
    $retval = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

//Here, I display the select option while the above values are retrived

 echo "<div align='center'><span class='style3'>{$row['home']} VS ".
             "{$row['away']} </span></div>".
             "<font color='#000000' size='2'>{$row['country']} | {$row['league']} | Time:{$row['starttime']} </font> <br> ".
             "<select name='gm[$row[gamecode]|$row[starttime]|$row[home]|$row[away]]' >
             <option value=''>Select option</option>
    <option value='1.80 01 Both Team to Score (YES)'>1.90 Both Team to Score (YES)</option>
    <option value='1.85 02 Both Team to Score (NO)'> 1.85 Both Team to Score (NO)</option>
    <option value='1.90 03 Over2.5(Total Goals)'>1.90 Over2.5(Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='1.80 04 Under 2.5(Total Goals)'>1.80 Under 2.5(Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='1.35 05 Over 1.5 (Total Goals)'>1.35 Over 1.5 (Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='2.60 06 Under 1.5 (Total Goals)'>2.60 Under 1.5 (Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='2.05 07 Draw(First Half)'>2.05 Draw(First Half)</option>
    <option value='1.55 08 Either Team Win (First Half)'>1.55 Either Team Win (First Half)</option>
    <option value='3.70 09 Draw(Full Time)'>3.70 Draw(Full Time)</option>
    <option value='1.20 10 Either Team Win (Full Time)'>1.20 Either Team Win (Full Time)</option>
    <option value='1.90 11 Even(Total Goals)'>1.90 Even(Total Goals)</option>
    <option value='1.90 12 Odd(Total Goals)'>1.90 Odd(Total Goals)</option>
    </select>".
             "<hr>";
    }//end While
   ------------------------------


$range = 3;

// if not on page 1, don't show back links
if ($currentpage > 1) {
   // show << link to go back to page 1
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'>First Page |</a> ";
   // get previous page num
   $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
   // show < link to go back to 1 page
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'>Previous Page |</a> ";
} // end if 

// loop to show links to range of pages around current page
for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {
   // if it's a valid page number...
   if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      // if we're on current page...
      if ($x == $currentpage) {
         // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
         echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
      // if not current page...
      } else {
         // make it a link
         echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
      } // end else
   } // end if 
} // end for

// if not on last page, show forward and last page links        
if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
   // get next page
   $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    // echo forward link for next page 
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>Next</a> ";
   // echo forward link for lastpage
   echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>| Last</a> ";
} // end if
-----------------------------------



?>
<br /><input type="submit" name="play" value="Calculate Bet" />
</form></div>
```

Here is the problem, If a user select any amount of option on page 1, and click page 2, and also select options on page 2, selects nothing on page 3 and proceed to submit form, only the option selected on the last selection page i.e page 2 is retrieved on the form processing page. How do i pass the values of option selected in all the pages down to the form processing page and not just the values selected on the last page?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to pass the selected option.

- Using Get Method (If there is no harm in passing info in URL)

You can pass the selected values in the URL e.g. `example.com/?option=true&option2=true`
And can retrieve i.e check if the option was selected or not using isset() function
Eg. `if(isset($_GET["option"])) { //do some stuffs }` or `if($_GET["option"]=="true") { //do some stuffs }`

- Using POST Method

There is very minor difference in the above mentioned method, get and the post one. 
YOu need to change `$_GET` to `$_POST` in each cases

Other two methods you can use cookies and session which I don't recommend

Comment: yes, i prefer the $_GET method in this case, I have been making numerous search on how i can save all the selected option in every page into URL